# How to set context of provided module through ProvidePlugin?

Tags: webpack

I have wrapper module over `promise-polyfill` -

```
/* jshint node: true */
/* global Promise: false */
"use strict";

if ( typeof Promise === "undefined" ) {
    module.exports = require('promise-polyfill');
} else {
    module.exports = Promise;
}
```

Then i inject it into all my modules:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'Promise': 'require-promise',
})
```

And i getting a problem. `Promise` is an empty object, instead native `Promise` or `undefined`. How i can pass context (`window` or `global`) to this module?

Generated code looks like:

```
function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(Promise) {/*** IMPORTS FROM imports-loader ***/
(function() {

/* jshint node: true */
/* global Promise: false */
"use strict";

console.log(Promise);

if ( typeof Promise === "undefined" ) {
    module.exports = __webpack_require__(59);
} else {
    module.exports = Promise;
}


/*** EXPORTS FROM exports-loader ***/
module.exports = Promise;
}.call(window));
/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */}.call(exports, __webpack_require__(7)))

/***/ },
```

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? Is `Promise` turning down as `{}`??

Comment: Yes. I updated answer with generated code

Comment: And `console.log(Promise)` outputs to.... ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'Promise': 'imports?Promise=>window.Promise!require-promise',
})
```